# How to do complex conditionals in Bash (mix of 'and' &&, 'or' || ...)

Tags: bash, syntax, conditional-statements

How do I accomplish something like the following in Bash?

```
if ("$a" == "something" || ($n == 2 && "$b" == "something_else")); then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
if [[ "$a" == "something" || ($n == 2 && "$b" == "something_else") ]]; then
```

In fact, the parentheses can be left out because of operator precedence, so it might also be written as

```
if [[ "$a" == "something" || $n == 2 && "$b" == "something_else" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if [[ "$a" == "something" ]] || [[ $n == 2 && "$b" == "something_else" ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: POSIX shell conforming:  `if [ "$a" = "something" -o \( $n -eq 2 -a "$b" = "something_else" \) ] ; then echo yes ; fi`

Comment: Pretty stupid how `[` doesn't use `[` as a parenthesis for grouping subexpressions, isn't it.